# Laravel ajax - The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to make an ajax in laravel and i get this: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD". The problem is that I've done ajax in my project before, only with this i have a problem. Can anyone help?

My route:

```
Route::get('/admin/clients-data','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@gravy');
Route::get('/admin/client-details/{slug}','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@clientdetails');
Route::post('/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@adddocumentstoclient');
```

My controller:

```
public function adddocumentstoclient(Request $request){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump('bump');
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
    }
```

And my js:

```
$('.tasks input').on('click', function() {
        var emptyValue = 0;
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            emptyValue += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        var documents_brought = [];
        var documents = $('.documents_brought input:checked').each(function(){
            documents_brought.push($(this).data('documentid'));
        });
        var client_id = $('.documents_brought').data('clientid');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "adddocumentstoclient",
            data: {'documents_brought':documents_brought,'client_id': client_id},
            success: function (html) {
                // returndata =  JSON.parse(html);;
                // toastr.success(returndata.message, returndata.title);
            }
        });
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your path is missmatch, try this one `url: "/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient",`

Comment: is not working, i tried

Comment: Tey with name route, and it will work `Route::post('/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@adddocumentstoclient')->name('adddocumentstoclient');` and on your blade ajax url will be `url: "{{ route('adddocumentstoclient') }}",`

Comment: Route::post('/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@adddocumentstoclient')->name('adddocumentstoclient');
Route [adddocumentstoclient] not defined

Comment: Seems like you need to clear route `php artisan route:clear` then try again. If not work then check the route list `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Yes man that was it, added ->name('adddocumentstoclient'), clear routes, and 'bum'. Thanks

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is here

```
Route::get('/admin/client-details/{slug}','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@clientdetails');
Route::post('/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient','App\Http\Controllers\ClientsController@adddocumentstoclient');
```

The first route is `get` and you accept `slug` param so whenever yo hit `/admin/client-details/adddocumentstoclient` it will be matched with first route which is `get` and you will never reach your second route.

Solution here to add a prefix before `slug` in `/admin/client-details/{slug}` or to change second route prefix `/admin/client-details/` to differentiate between both routes.